# Prevent Visual Studio Web Test from changing request details

Tags: visual-studio, testing, webtest, xmla

I have a service that accepts Xmla queries for Analysis services, often times those queries themselves will have a string that contains a fragment that looks something like

```
{{[Time].[Year].[All]}}
```

Recording these requests works fine but when I try to re-run the test I get an error from the test runner...

Request failed: Exception occurred: There is no context parameter with the name ' [Time].[Year].[All]' in the WebTestContext

This was confusing for some time but when I asked VS to generate a coded version of the test I was able to see the problem a bit better. VS searches for the '{{' and '}}' tokens and makes changes, considering those areas to refer to Context parameters, the code looks like

```
this.Context["\n\t[Time].[Year].[All]"].ToString()
```

Anyone know how to instruct Visual Studio to not perform this replacement operation? Or another way around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Using double curly braces eg. "{{  }}" is redundant. You only need to use a single set of braces eg. "{  }" or if this code is generated it will also work with spaces between the sets of braces eg. "{ {  } }"

Answer (score 0):

The context-substitution behaviour is automatic and not controllable as far as I know, but there are some ways to work around it:

- Generate coded tests and then undo what Visual Studio has done, e.g. replace `this.Context["\n\t[Time].[Year].[All]"].ToString()` with `"{{[Time].[Year].[All]}}"` everywhere it appears.  This is kind of awful though.
- Put the `{{[Time].[Year].[All]}}` string into a context parameter and use that context parameter instead of the raw string.  Visual Studio only applies context parameter substitution once, so it will leave the resulting string value alone.
- A third possibility is to alter all of the xmla strings `{{[foo]}}` to be `[[[foo]]]` and then write a WebTestPlugin or WebTestRequestPlugin that converts `[[[foo]]]` back to `{{[foo]}}` in the **PreRequest** event during test execution.  The automatic substitution happens before PreRequest so that is a safe time to put them back to curly-braces.